# Materialize css Tabs with Angular not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, materialize

Tried to add to my app(Angular 1.** & Materialize) tabs-component Materialize CSS - always gives me error about

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tabs is not a function
```

added jquery script many different ways:

```
   $(window).load(function(){
        $('ul.tabs').tabs();
    });
```

And Ive got all dependencies which I need, but result still the same. Did somebody faced with it?

Comment: I suggest you to use Angular Material (from Google) https://material.angularjs.org/latest/ instead of MaterializeCSS

Comment: https://krescruz.github.io/angular-materialize/#tabs Angular directives for materialize components